# API to get all the resources of a content type in a Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any API to get all the files of particular content type in a Eclipse project?

One option is to visit all resources and collect the files of a content type.

I am looking at API which takes IProject and content type id as parameters and returns IPath or IFile or IResource objects. For example get all Java files in a project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.  Your idea is generally how that would be done.

Comment: I realized it. IResourceVisitor and IResource.accept(IResourceVisitor) came handy for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thats what I used to find all c files in a the current project:

```
    public static ArrayList<IResource> getAllCFilesInProject(){
    ArrayList<IResource> allCFiles = new ArrayList<IResource>();
    IWorkspaceRoot myWorkspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = FileParaviserUtils.getCurrentProject();

    IPath path = project.getLocation();

    recursiveFindCFiles(allCFiles,path,myWorkspaceRoot);
    return allCFiles;
}

private static void recursiveFindCFiles(ArrayList<IResource> allCFiles,IPath path, IWorkspaceRoot myWorkspaceRoot){
    IContainer  container =  myWorkspaceRoot.getContainerForLocation(path);

    try {
        IResource[] iResources;
        iResources = container.members();
        for (IResource iR : iResources){
            // for c files
            if ("c".equalsIgnoreCase(iR.getFileExtension()))
                allCFiles.add(iR);
            if (iR.getType() == IResource.FOLDER){
                IPath tempPath = iR.getLocation();
                recursiveFindCFiles(allCFiles,tempPath,myWorkspaceRoot);
            }
        }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static IProject getCurrentProject(){
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (window != null)
    {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
        Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
        if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable)
        {
            IProject project = (IProject)((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
            return project;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [release notes of eclipse3.1](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.core.resources/old_build_notes.html?view=co) did mention at the time (June 2005) a change in the heuristics for content type matching.
It was related on [bug 90218](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=90218), part of [bug 82986](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=82986) (enhancements to matching in 3.1), which references [**bug 86862**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86862) ("need API for related custom objects lookup")

That API didn't make it, but the [code is available](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=18538) for you to reuse.

```
public Object[] findRelatedObjects(IContentType type, String fileName, IRelatedRegistry registry) {
  List allRelated = new ArrayList();
  // first add any objects directly related to the content type
  Object[] related = registry.getRelatedObjects(type);
  for (int i = 0; i < related.length; i++) {
    allRelated.add(related[i]);
  }
  // backward compatibility requested - add any objects related to the file name
  if (fileName != null) {
    related = registry.getRelatedObjects(fileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < related.length; i++) {
      if (!allRelated.contains(related[i])) {
        // we don't want to return duplicates
        allRelated.add(related[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  // now add any indirectly related objects, walking up the content type hierarchy 
  while ((type = type.getBaseType()) != null) {
    related = registry.getRelatedObjects(type);
    for (int i = 0; i < related.length; i++) {
      if (!allRelated.contains(related[i])) {
        // we don't want to return duplicates          
        allRelated.add(related[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return allRelated.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is related to files of particular content type. Perhaps my question is not clear, I edited the question with example.