# get IFile[] using Path

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have the org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path object. This will have some value like Test/src/jsp -- where Test is the project name. From this I want to get the list of files ie IFile[], in that path.
Can you please suggest a way.

Comment: You might be able to adapt this answer to retrieve the list of files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320808/220381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the src/ folder via `IFolder folder = project.getFolder(new Path("/src/"))`
and then getting all resources from this Folder via `IResource[] resources = folder.members()`.

So you only need to extract all IFiles e.g.

`for(IResource resource : resources) {

if(resource instanceof IFile)

 //do something

}`